# FileNotFoundException in Silex when returning a php image resource

Tags: php, response, silex

i have an API route in my silex server that renders a php image resource and returns it via a `BinaryFileResponse`. I tried several response types and the BinaryFileResponse was the only one working properly. Nevertheless, every time i use this route to retrieve an image i get following error message in the logs:

```
silex: CRITICAL Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException: The file "1" does not exist (uncaught exception) at /opt/pyriand3r/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php line 41 | host='sv35' exception='error'
```

I believe this is, because i do not return an actual file but only a file resource not persisted in the filesystem. 
Is there a way to erase this error without saving the image temporarly in the filesystem? Maybe another response type or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BinaryFileResponse` is indeed intended for items in the filesystem. For your scenario, `StreamedResponse` would be appropriate.

In case `StreamedResponse` was among the response classes you unsuccessfully tried to get to work, you should post the failing code.

Comment: I don't know what was wrong the last time because i am sure i have tested the `StreamedResponse` without success. Now it is working. Thanks!